# Segmentation fault error while installing dynd-python in Python 2.7 environment

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to install dynd-python using

```
conda install -c anaconda dynd-python
```

On Debian and getting the following error,

```
INFO startup-script-url: Downloading and Extracting Packages
INFO startup-script-url: Preparing transaction: ...working... done
INFO startup-script-url: Verifying transaction: ...working... done
INFO startup-script-url: Executing transaction: ...working... done
[  232.714462] conda[6368]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f1a73d295a0 sp 00007f1a2723d6c0 error 6 in libpython2.7.so.1.0.c~ (deleted)[7f1a73c4d000+17d000]
[  232.727548] Code: 08 4c 89 ff ff 50 30 49 83 2e 01 75 27 49 8b 46 08 4c 89 f7 ff 50 30 eb 1b 90 48 8d 50 f8 48 89 94 24 a8 00 00 00 48 8b 78 f8 <48> 83 2f 01 0f 84 29 41 00 00 48 8b 84 24 a8 00 00 00 48 39 44 24
kernel: [  232.714462] conda[6368]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f1a73d295a0 sp 00007f1a2723d6c0 error 6 in libpython2.7.so.1.0.c~ (deleted)[7f1a73c4d000+17d000]
kernel: [  232.727548] Code: 08 4c 89 ff ff 50 30 49 83 2e 01 75 27 49 8b 46 08 4c 89 f7 ff 50 30 eb 1b 90 48 8d 50 f8 48 89 94 24 a8 00 00 00 48 8b 78 f8 <48> 83 2f 01 0f 84 29 41 00 00 48 8b 84 24 a8 00 00 00 48 39 44 24
INFO startup-script-url: ./init_actions.sh: line 52:  3309 ***Segmentation fault      conda install -c anaconda dynd-python***
INFO startup-script-url: BuildFailed: Custom Image Initialization Actions Failed. Please check your initialization script.
```

Using Python2.7

Any advice how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which Dataproc image version are you using?

Comment: Using 1.3 version of GCP Dataproc:
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloud-dataproc/global/images/dataproc-1-3-deb9-20200220-000000-rc01

Image Base family is :1.3.52-debian9

Comment: Are you able to SSH in when that happens and debug directly? If so, does it consistently segfault on any `sudo conda install` command? Does `sudo apt-get install` work if you try to install something like `sudo apt-get install vim`? What if you run `sudo conda update` first?

Comment: Dennis, Its not consistent and now i am able to install the dynd-python library, not sure why i am getting this error frequently.